# Have a Python dictionary a return default value for non-included keys

Tags: python

For example, if a dictionary is defined `pythonDict = {a: 1, b: 2}` and it is referenced `pythonDict["c"]` or `pythonDict["d"]`, can the dictionary be defined a default value for any key that isn't listed, without listing all the possibilities?

I'd like to have a reference in one line without an additional "if" statement to check if the key is included.

Comment: from collections import defaultdict

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> pythonDict = defaultdict(lambda: 100, a=1, b=2)
>>> pythonDict["c"]
100
```

Answer (score -2):

Use `dict.get(key, default value)`.
It returns value when key is in dict. Otherwise, it returns default value.

Example code.

```
dic = {"a":1, "b":2}
my_default = "default"
print(dic.get("a", my_default))
print(dic.get("c", my_default))
```